# cannot make ASP.NET call from ASP return a String[] that's usable

Tags: asp-classic

I definitely searched for this, but I can't find the answer, even though it seems so trivial.

I have a variable in ASP.NET that returns a string.

```
string[] arrayOfThings { get { return new string[] { ... } } }
```

And I have call to it in ASP

```
Dim someString
For Each someString In someClass.arrayOfThings
    # Do Something with someString
Next
```

This does not work. It returns a 'Type Mismatch' Exception.

When I try to debug, IsArray(someClass.arrayOfThings) returns True, but it has no Count, no attributes, nothing. UBound(someClass.arrayOfThings) is 0, which is what I would expect since it only has 1 element in it. However, I'm unable to reference the element by someClass.arrayOfThings(0)

I'm new to ASP, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I so wish ASP was strongly typed.

Edit: I tried creating an Array with the same value, and compare it to what I get from arrayOfThings, and in the debugger window they look identical, but in one case I can loop through it and in the other, I cannot.

Just FYI, currently I have it working like this:

I have a variable in ASP.NET that returns a string.

```
string arrayOfThings { get { return String.Join(",", new string[] { ... }) } }
```

And then in ASP

```
Dim someString
For Each someString In Split(someClass.arrayOfThings, ",")
    # Do Something with someString
Next
```

And this works.

Comment: A classic asp array and a .NET array are not the same thing. How are you assigning a .NET array to a classic asp variable? Can you show the code? How are you populating `someClass` in classic asp?

Comment: I'm not assigning it to a variable. I don't populate someClass in classic. I just set someClass = Server.CreateObject("someClass"), and then Call someClass.someConstructor.

Comment: Have you have made `someClass` COM visible?

Comment: Yes. Currently I just have arrayOfThings be a comma-separated string, and then I do a split to recover the array. I just wanted to know if there's a more elegant solution. It's the type (or converstion from ASP.NET string[] to ASP Array) that doesn't play nice, everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this approach instead:-

```
 object[] arrayOfThings { get { return new object[] { ... } } }
```

The problem with using a string array is that it marshals as a SAFEARRAY of BSTR in COM speak.  However VBScript can only cope with SAFEARRAY of VARIANT.  Using object *should* result in an array of Variant.